# configure: error: Can't find libvorbis while installing recordmydesktop-0.3.8.1

Tags: linux, vorbis

I'm trying to install recordmydesktop-0.3.8.1 under rhel6.4 x86_64.
while running ./configure I get the following error message:
configure: error: Can't find libvorbis
But I have libvorbisfile.so.X files under my /usr/lib directory. The headers 
codec.h, vorbisenc.h and vorbisfile.h also exists in my /usr/include/vorbis directory.
Could you help to resolve this issue please?

Comment: The link /usr/lib64/libvorbis.so  is missing ?  Then reinstall libvorbis-devel : # yum reinstall libvorbis-devel

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem while installing recordMyDesktop. I found a simple solution. I installed libvorbis:

```
sudo apt-get install libvorbis-dev
```

If it also asks for other packages simply add the package name as following pattern:

```
sudo apt-get install lib[library-name]-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall existing libvorbis and try below steps to re-install.

```
cd /opt

wget http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/vorbis/libvorbis-1.3.4.tar.gz

tar xzvf libvorbis-1.3.4.tar.gz

cd libvorbis-1.3.4

./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --with-ogg="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared

make

make install
```